# radio button click doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons on my MVC page. When I click on 'Yes' button it enables the textbox but when I click on 'No' it doesn't disable the textbox. What could be the problem?

```
    $('#rdoDate').click(function () {
        debugger;
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case 'N':
                $("#txtDate").attr("disabled", true);
                break;
            case 'Y':
                $("#txtDate").removeAttr("disabled");
                break;
        }
    });

   <%=Html.RadioButton("rdoDate","Y")%><label>Yes</label> 
    <%=Html.RadioButton("rdoDate", "N", true)%><label>No</label>

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.txtDate, new { id = "txtDate", disabled = true })%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define two same ID on a html page.
If "rdoDate" is an ID, you'll have to define an other one for the second line, like :

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("rdoDateY","Y")%><label>Yes</label> 
<%=Html.RadioButton("rdoDateN", "N", true)%><label>No</label>
```

But if it's a name, the problem is in your Js code, where you try to access ID element (via #) instead of name elements (I don't know Html.RadioButton).
If it's the case, you should locate your element like :

```
$('input[name="rdoDate"]').click (...);
```

Hope this helps :)